# Check to see if an email is already in the database using prepared statements

Tags: php, mysqli, prepared-statement

I am trying to change my code to msqli prepared statements from mysql. I am not sure how to adapt my code that currently works to check if there is an email already in the database. Below is the code I am currently using that works. How do I change this into a prepared statement and get the same result?

```
//if email is equal to an email already in the database, display an error message

if(mysql_num_rows(mysql_query("SELECT * FROM users WHERE email = '".mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['email'])."'")))
{
  echo "<p class='red'>Email is already registered with us</p>";
} else {
  // missing code?
}
```

Comment: Welcome on SO. I've reformatted your post to the best of my abilities. Make sure to read the FAQ to get used to mark up. There is some code missing you probably wanted to post.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Should be something like this:

```
// enable error reporting for mysqli
mysqli_report(MYSQLI_REPORT_ERROR | MYSQLI_REPORT_STRICT);
// create mysqli object
$mysqli = new mysqli(/* fill in your connection info here */);

$email = $_POST['email']; // might want to validate and sanitize this first before passing to database...

// set query
$query = "SELECT COUNT(*) FROM users WHERE email = ?";

// prepare the query, bind the variable and execute
$stmt = $mysqli->prepare($query);
$stmt->bind_param('s', $email);
$stmt->execute();

// grab the result
$stmt->bind_result($numRows);
$stmt->fetch();

if ($numRows) {
    echo "<p class='red'>Email is already registered with us</p>";
} else {
    // ....
}
```

This link may help you as well:

http://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php